# Using unmanaged C#-DLL in C++/FORTRAN

Tags: c#, fortran, pinvoke

I am working on my master thesis and need your help! Btw I am studying mechanical enginneering... so my programming skills are limited.

Here my problem:

I have a DLL, which is created in C# ( I cannot post it, because it is a part of an unpublished research). But it gives me some Arrays ( 1D-Array [], 2DArray[,] ).

For a simulation with ABAQUS I need to import that C#-DLL in C++ and/or FORTRAN.

I found the solution from Robert Giesecke to create a unmanaged DLL. I think this is the easiest solution for me. (Of course if someone has another solution for me, a wrapper or something, please post it)

Here my 1D Array example for a unmanaged C#-DLL created with R.Giesecke Template:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using RGiesecke.DllExport;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Testme
{
    class Test
    {

        [DllExport("Get1DArray", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static double Get1DArray([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 1)]  double[] STRESS, int i)
        {
            return STRESS[i];
        }

    }
}
```

and here my 2D Array code:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using RGiesecke.DllExport;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Testme
{
    class Test
    {

        public static int idx(int a, int b) { int cols = 2; return a * cols + b; }

        [DllExport("Set2DArray", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static int Set2DArray([In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 1)] int[] STRAIN, int len)
        {
            STRAIN[idx(0, 0)] = 0;
            STRAIN[idx(0, 1)] = 1;
            STRAIN[idx(1, 0)] = 2;
            STRAIN[idx(1, 1)] = 3;
            STRAIN[idx(2, 0)] = 4;
            STRAIN[idx(2, 1)] = 5;

            return 0;
        }

    }
}
```

The Build have succeeded at both. How can I import the DLLs in C++ and/or FORTRAN?

Thx in advance!

Comment: Is your c# dll COM visible?

Comment: I am not sure. So your approuch would be to do it with COM?
I am wondering... is it so difficult to pass an array from c# to c++/fortran? I cannot find a example to do it with COM or a C++/CLR wrapper or something else.

Comment: Well I'm a little out of the loop on this subject at the moment, but Alan Gordon explain that problems quite well in his book `The .NET and COM interoperability`

Comment: This is actually nothing at all to do with C#, and all about how to consume DLLs in Fortran. Find out about that by reading the documentation of whichever compiler you use. Bear in mind that they all do this a little differently, so it's no good asking about Fortran as if it were standardised. It's not. Doesn't ABAQUS integrate well with Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compile your C#-DLL with tool from R. Giesecke, you should also get a *.lib file with it. 
You need to reference this lib in your FORTRAN linker settings as additional library dependency. It contains all the code required to load the DLL and make the functions in the DLL available.

In your FORTRAN code you need to declare the imported methods with the following statements:

```
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLIMPORT, ALIAS:'_MethodeName::MethodName
```

BTW: COM visibility is not needed if using RGiesecke. The access to the C# is native and not via COM (also making it considerably faster).